# rand() numbers addicted in function in C

Tags: c, function, random

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int dorand(){
int i;
srand(time(0));
i = rand()%3+1;
return i;
}

int main (){
printf("\n %d \n", dorand());
printf("\n %d \n", dorand());
printf("\n %d \n", dorand());
printf("\n %d \n", dorand());
return 0;
}
```

The issue is: the four printf are printing the same number.
When I do the rand() directly in the main function there is no problem at all but when I call a function to do so the random generation gets addicted to the same number. Do someone have some experience to share, please?

I've tried:

```
int main (){
srand(time(0)) //seeding in the main function before calling the dorand function
printf("\n %d \n", dorand());
printf("\n %d \n", dorand());
printf("\n %d \n", dorand());
printf("\n %d \n", dorand());
return 0;
}
```

Also

```
int dorand(){
int i;
i = 0; //clearing the variable before attributing a new rand value
srand(time(0));
i = rand()%3+1;
return i;
}
```

Sorry if I mistook something, thanks for helping

Comment: You keep resetting the seed.

Comment: try to not change seed every function call. try call this `srand(time(0));` once only at main (or elsewhere).

Comment: worked, thanks a lot guys

Comment: Glad we could help.  Feel free to [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

The `srand` function seeds the random number generator.  For a given seed value, the same set of random numbers gets generated.

Since you re-seed each time you want a random number, using the current time as the seed, assuming each call to the function happens in the same second the random number function is seeded with the same value, so you keep getting the same "random" numbers.

You should call `srand` only once at the beginning of your program.  Remove the call from `dorand` and put it at the top of `main`.